# Preserve appearance of dragged A element when using html5 draggable attribute

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, draggable

How can i preserve appearance of the dragged A element when using 'draggable' html5 attribute. On some browsers (Safari & Chrome) when dragging anchor, dragged helper is replaced with browser native implementation of dragged element as seen on the screenshots:

*When dragging DIV*

[image: When dragging DIV]

*When dragging A*

[image: When dragging A]

HTML

```
<div class="draggable">Draggable DIV</div>
<a href="" class="draggable">Draggable A</a>
```

CSS

```
$('.draggable').attr('draggable', true);
```

Here is the quick JSBin i assembled to demonstrate this issue http://jsbin.com/pihayeceza/1/edit

Thanks

Comment: Maybe not a real solution, but removing the href attribute seems to correct it. I guess the browser's default behavior when dragging an anchor with an href is to have the url as the placeholder, and that's overriding what happens when there isn't an href.

Comment: This may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#Drag_Effects

Comment: I am curious as to why you are using jQuery to add the `draggable` attribute? It may be out of context but it seems to me you would be better off simply adding `draggable="true"` into the HTML elements?

Comment: @Billy it was easer for me to assemble the jsbin example using the jQuery, nothing more

Answer (score 10):

I'm able to preserve the appearance of the dragged element by using [`DataTransfer.setDragImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#setDragImage.28.29). If I add the following code to the JavaScript in your jsbin instance, it work for me on Firefox, Chrome and Safari:

```
$('a.draggable').on('dragstart', function (ev) {
  var dt = ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
  // In IE browsers, setDragImage does not exist. However, the issue we are 
  // trying to fix does not happen in these broswers. So if setDragImage is not
  // available, then just don't do anything.
  if (dt.setDragImage) 
    dt.setDragImage(ev.target, 0, 0);

});
```

The `dataTransfer` field of the event has a [`DataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object associated with the drag operation. You have to fetch it from the original DOM Event rather than from the jQuery Event wrapper, so `ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer`.

For IE browsers, `setDragImage` is not present but the problem reported in the question *does not occur in the first place* so if `setDragImage` is absent, we just don't call it.

A [bin](http://jsbin.com/foyigusovo/1/edit?html,js,output) with the updated code.

Comment: This looks like a really easy way to accomplish what i've set to do, but caniuse.com (http://caniuse.com/#feat=dragndrop) states that internet explorer does not support setDragImage method. Any suggestion for a workaround?

Comment: Absolutely fabulous! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

This problem happens because the default behavior of dragging a link with an href attribute is to create an image containing the url to be used as the drag placeholder. You can fix this by removing the href attribute, however, to get around that without having to remove the href attribute you can use mousedown/up event handlers to remove the attribute and then re-add it, leaving the anchors clickable*.

```js
$('.draggable').attr('draggable', true).on('mousedown', function () {
  if ($(this).is('a')) {
    $(this).data('href', this.href);
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
  }
}).on('mouseup', function () {
  if ($(this).is('a')) {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).data('href'));
  }
}).on('click', function () {
  console.log(this.href);
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="draggable">Draggable DIV</div>
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="draggable">Draggable A</a>
```

*Note: stack snippets doesn't let you follow the link.

Comment: I expected setting `event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed` to `copy` would solve this, however, it didn't seem to have any effect in chrome.

Comment: If i don't find a workaround for ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer support in internet explorer, i think i'll use this solution. Did you test this solution in browsers to see which browsers support it?

Comment: No, I didn't. Just chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your anchor tags with a div and set draggable="false" on the anchor tag.

```
<div class="draggable">
    <a href="" draggable="false">Draggable A</a>
</div>
```

You will need additional styling to prevent the button/link from looking blue and underlined.

```
.draggable a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

modified your jsbin here
http://jsbin.com/rebayif/edit

Comment: This help me a lot, since i already had an draggable="true" element outside my <a href >. So just adding a draggable="false" on the <a> solved this for me. Thanks! +1